# Open CTI in Canvas

Tags: canvas, cti

I've a call center that have a canvas.
When I try using the functions of the SF Open CTI (interaction.js), as the sforce.interaction.cti.setSoftphoneWidth function, nothing happens.

If I'm updating in the "interaction.js" the window, and replacing "window.parent.postMessage" by "top.postMessage", it's working.

It there something that I am not doing correctly?

Regards,
Ilan

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, you can check

[Open CTI methods don't work in canvas application (source origin's function returning false)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117232/open-cti-methods-dont-work-in-canvas-application-source-origins-function-retu/122729#122729)

They fixed this library in summer 16 release.

So you need to get account which is already migrated to summer 16 or wait untill your instance migrates.

You can found calendar here: https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/calendar